# Android studio : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

So i was going through many stackoverflow answers and i tried applying them on my code, but i still couldn't find fix for this error. Also this error happens only when i try to Run the app only. i can build the project without any issues.

So this is the error i'm getting.

```
error: cannot access zzbgl class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found
```

Also after that i'm getting this as a warning

```
D:\FinalProject\app\src\main\java\com\example\www\mytaxiapp\Welcome.java:
uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

So far i tried changing the versions and commenting, also adding and removing dependencies, but still i was unable to find a solution for this. hope someone can help me here.

**This is my gradle APP level file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.www.mytaxiapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.github.glomadrian:MaterialAnimatedSwitch:1.1@aar'
implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.2'
implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
//Add Library
implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
}
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**My Welcome.class file imports**

```
package com.example.www.mytaxiapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire;
import com.firebase.geofire.GeoLocation;
import com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class Welcome extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener
{
```

Answer (score 4):

Updating location service did the work for me ;)

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Google GMS is a very large dependency. You could try to enable multidex (by adding following line to your defaultConfig:

```
defaultConfig {    
...
   multiDexEnabled true
...
}
```

If you are targeting lower Android-versions, it can be, that you need to include support-Multidex as a dependency:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

In this case, you should add a Application-class whilst you overwrite attachBaseContext like this:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    MultiDex.install(this);
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
}
```

Please don't forget the clear project and gradle-sync.

Hope that helps.